# Record admin changes in log?

Tags: 7, users

Is there a way of recording changes made to a Drupal site in a log?

Im working as part of a team and some members are off site. We're running into issues where changes are made to the path pattern of nodes by other members, and it would be really useful to be able to check what changes have been made recently. Even better would be to know which admin user made the changes. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Drupal 8 configuration is also stored in files, so you can commit it to git and have a full log. As far as I know there is no mechanism to record all actions of users in any version of Drupal.

If you insist, you can implement hook_form_submit() for every form and add additional save function to record who, when and what, but it will be hard to use log created this way.

Other approach is to use [Features](http://drupal.org/project/features) - let them develop their parts on their copies and just send you packages with working pieces.

Comment: [`configuration`](https://drupal.org/project/configuration) module is also similar to features but some people say it's better.

Comment: @Beebee - Configuration has different purpose. Features keeps track of everything it's told to. Configuration Management on the other hand is a contrib implementation of what D8 is doing - keeping config on hdd. So both can be used, depending on the way development is supposed to happen, and each one is better - for the usage it was written for.