# Logging changes/modifications in Drupal

Tags: 7

**Is there a standard way or a module that can log all node/settings modifications/updates?**

I don't feel watchdog would be the best place, as it is an error log and not an update log, but I suppose it would do.

In Magento CMS, it might look something like this: http://amasty.com/admin-actions-log.html

We have had instances where something was changed and we didn't know who made the change or when the change was made.  Having a change log would have been very helpful.

Comment: [Journal](https://www.drupal.org/project/journal) maybe?

Comment: Revisioning could help.

Comment: Yes, node revisioning does help.  Although there were some settings that were changed in the Admin, not on a single node.  For instance, modifying permissions.  It would be great to have a system that keeps track of all modifications on the site.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Record admin changes in log?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/75992/record-admin-changes-in-log)

Comment: See http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/87177/16495 for settings.